# Artificial ant colony algorithm for graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization

let's assume we have ant at node $1$ and she has $\{2,3,4\}$ vertices. How do I compute which one she choose? I mean if the formula $p_{ij}(k)$ is the probability of $k$-th ant at node $i$ choose $j$ node, for example, do I take $j=2$, compute the probability and if it satisfies $random(0,1)<p_{12}(k)$, the ant choose $j=2$, if not move to next vertex $j=3$ until the inequality is satisfied? 
The next question is, can you recommend me the sources, where I can find conversion from this algorithm graph version to optimizing function version. Thank you.

Comment: I'm super-confused.  Do you have one ant or multiple ants?  You ask how to compute which edge the ant chooses but then you say $p_{ij}(k)$ is the probability the ant chooses node $j$, so what are you asking?  Does $p_{ij}(k)$ already answer your question?  I think part of the problem is that it is not clear what the setting is, it is not clear what exactly the notation represents, and it is not clear exactly what your question is.

Comment: Let's say I got probabilities $23.58\%, 35.27\%, 41.15\%$ respectively for $2, 3, 4$ vertex. How to code which one to choose?

Comment: I'm confused about the question too, but based on your comment, are you looking for the following? For simplicity, suppose we have two events such that $P(A) = 0.4$ and $P(B)=0.6$. Pick a random integer $r$ between 1 and 10. If $1 \leq r \leq 4$, let $A$ happen; otherwise, when $5 \leq r \leq 10$, let $B$ happen. You should be able to generalize from here to more events (divide the probability space appropriately in case of more events) or higher precision (take a larger probability space).